# Using Raspberry Pi 2 W with ADS1015, after taking analog reading and copying value to another object the value changes in original object

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, adc, raspberry-pi, python

```
#create class of Voltage readings
class Reading:
def __init__(self, name, value, voltage, test):
    self.name = name
    self.value= value #decimal value of 10 bit resolution value after taking reading
    self.voltage = voltage #measured voltage after taking reading
    self.test = test #True = passed test, False = failed test
    
PS1 = Reading("PS1", 0, 0.0, False)


def Test_1():


#turn on main power and test power supplies

t_begin = datetime.now() #take timestamp for referance to beginning of test
GPIO.output(Sim_Main_Pwr, True)  # turn on main power by activating relay K8
time.sleep(1)  # delay 2 seconds for stabilization

#take a reading of Power supply 1 voltage
i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b00000001)  # select channel on the i2c mux
PS1_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS) # read information to ads object from pin 2 of ADS1015
print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V) 
print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.value) 
print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage) 

PS1.value = PS1_V.value
PS1.voltage = PS1_V.voltage

print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V) 
print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.value) 
print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage) 

print("PS1 : " , PS1) 
print("PS1 : " , PS1.value) 
print("PS1 : " , PS1.voltage)
```

after executing this snippet of code the following is the output:

[image]

At first the original `.value` and `.voltage` changed drastically but now the values are only changing a little bit. I don't understand what changed besides I am now printing them out. There is probably a better way to put the `AnalogIn.value` and `AnalogIn.voltage` into the class `Reading` I created but it works as it is besides the original value changing a bit now.

I tried to change the way I passed the values to the class `Reading` I created but couldn't figure out a better way to do that. So I am still going to use the intermediary object to hold the values in the `AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS)` line of code and then pass the values after.

Don't know why the original object `PS1_V` voltage and value changed after copying the values over to PS1 and if it is a concern. Could the PS1 values change later?

All my question is about is how the data stored in the `PS1_V` object could change after copying that data to another object. And also why the object that the data was copied to (PS1) doesn't exactly match either the before or after copied object's data. Is that like a Raspberry Pi thing?

Edited to add the entire code as reference:

```
import board
import busio
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
from smbus import SMBus
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1015 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn



#################################################################################
#define GPIO pins numbers
#################################################################################
# set GPIO numbering mode and define output pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Outputs
Sim_Main_Pwr = 5
Sim_52A_A = 6
Sim_52A_B = 12
Sim_52A_C = 13
Sim_Rly_Trip = 14
Sim_Rly_Close = 15
Sim_Interlock = 16
Sim_Lockout = 19
Sim_Spare = 20
Sim_PB_Trip = 21
Sim_PB_Close = 26

#inputs
Err_NO = 22
Err_NC = 23
Ready_NO = 24
Ready_NC = 26

#set pin directions
GPIO.setup(Sim_Main_Pwr, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_52A_A, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_52A_B, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_52A_C, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_Rly_Trip, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_Rly_Close, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_Interlock, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_Lockout , GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_Spare, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_PB_Trip, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Sim_PB_Close, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Err_NO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Err_NC, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Ready_NO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Ready_NC, GPIO.IN)
#####################################################################################
#Define ADS pins where info is found
Counter_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 1 of the TCA9548A
LED_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 1 of the TCA9548A
PS1_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 1 of the TCA9548A
Mux_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 1 of the TCA9548A

PS2_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 2 of the TCA9548A
PS3_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 2 of the TCA9548A
Q5_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 2 of the TCA9548A
Q7_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 2 of the TCA9548A

PB_Trip_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 3 of the TCA9548A
PB_Close_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 3 of the TCA9548A
Interlock_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 3 of the TCA9548A
A_52A_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 3 of the TCA9548A

Rly_Trip_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 4 of the TCA9548A
Rly_Close_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 4 of the TCA9548A
Cap_V_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 4 of the TCA9548A
Spare_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 4 of the TCA9548A

Q4_MCU_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 5 of the TCA9548A
Q5_MCU_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 5 of the TCA9548A
Q6_MCU_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 5 of the TCA9548A
Q7_MCU_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 5 of the TCA9548A

Dip_Out_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 6 of the TCA9548A
Dip_A2_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 6 of the TCA9548A
Dip_A1_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 6 of the TCA9548A
Dip_A0_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 6 of the TCA9548A

LOP_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 7 of the TCA9548A
B_52A_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 7 of the TCA9548A
C_52A_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 7 of the TCA9548A
Lockout_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 7 of the TCA9548A

PS4_ADS = ADS.P0  # counter voltage is located on pin 0 of ADS on channel 8 of the TCA9548A
PS5_ADS = ADS.P1  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 1 of ADS on channel 8 of the TCA9548A
Q4_Vg_ADS = ADS.P2  # PS1 voltage is located on pin 2 of ADS on channel 8 of the TCA9548A
Q6_Vg_ADS = ADS.P3  # Power supply mux voltage is located on pin 3 of ADS on channel 8 of the TCA9548A

#################################################################################
#Initialize global variables
#################################################################################
Abort = 0
thresh_L_12V = 3.4
thresh_H_12V = 3.7
thresh_L_5V = 2.8
thresh_H_5V = 3.0

#create class of Voltage readings
class Reading:
    def __init__(self, name, value, voltage, test):
        self.name = name
        self.value= value #decimal value of 10 bit resolution value after taking reading
        self.voltage = voltage #measured voltage after taking reading
        self.test = test #True = passed test, False = failed test
        
        
        
        
        
PS1 = Reading("PS1", 0, 0.0, False)


def Test_1():
    
    
    #turn on main power and test power supplies
    
    t_begin = datetime.now() #take timestamp for referance to beginning of test
    GPIO.output(Sim_Main_Pwr, True)  # turn on main power by activating relay K8
    time.sleep(1)  # delay 2 seconds for stabilization

    #take a reading of Power supply 1 voltage
    i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b00000001)  # select channel on the i2c mux
    PS1_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS) # read information to ads object from pin 2 of ADS1015
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.value) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage) 
    
    PS1.value = PS1_V.value
    PS1.voltage = PS1_V.voltage
    
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.value) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage) 
    
    print("PS1 : " , PS1) 
    print("PS1 : " , PS1.value) 
    print("PS1 : " , PS1.voltage) 
    
    
    #print("PS1: ", PS1_V.value, PS1_V.voltage)  # print values read
    
    # take a reading of Power supply Multiplexor voltage
    #i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b00000001)  # select channel on the i2c mux
    Mux_V = AnalogIn(ads, Mux_ADS)  # read information to ads object from pin 2 of ADS1015
    print("Mux: ", Mux_V.value, Mux_V.voltage)  # print values read
    # take a reading of Power supply 1 voltage
    
    #i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b00000010)  # select channel on the i2c mux
    #PS3_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS3_ADS)
    #print(PS3_V.value, PS3_V.voltage)  # print values read
    #PS2_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS2_ADS)
    #print(PS2_V.value, PS2_V.voltage)  # print values read
    
    i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b10000000)  # select channel on the i2c mux
    PS4_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS4_ADS)
    print("PS4: ", PS4_V.value, PS4_V.voltage)  # print values read
    PS5_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS5_ADS)
    print("PS5: ",PS5_V.value, PS5_V.voltage)  # print values read
    
    #compare values to thresholds to determine if power supplies are good and the board passes the test
    if PS1.voltage > thresh_L_12V and PS1.voltage < thresh_H_12V:
            PS1.test = True
    
    #print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage)     
    print("PS1 : " , PS1.voltage, PS1.test) 
    t_end = datetime.now()
    print(t_end - t_begin)#see how long test 1 sampling took
    # cleanup the GPIO pins before ending
    GPIO.cleanup()
    
    
    



#declare function to set correct channel passed by object
# setup of I2C
i2cbus = SMBus(1)  # create a new I2C bus
TCA_addr = 0x70  # address of TCA9548A
ADS_addr = 0x48  # address of the ads1015

i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b00000001)  # select channel on the i2c mux

#test to check channel selected
channel = i2cbus.read_byte(TCA_addr)  # read TCA_addr to channel object
print(channel)  # read and verify channel selected by Mux

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA) #select pins for raspberry pi to perform I2C comms
ads = ADS.ADS1015(i2c)  # create i2c object for ads1015



"""
# blink LEDs 10 times
for x in range(0, 2):
    GPIO.output(Main_Pwr, True)  # turn on main power by activating relay K8
    time.sleep(3)  # delay
    PS1_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS)  # read information to ads object from pin 2 of ADS1015
    print(PS1_V.value, PS1_V.voltage)  # print values read
    time.sleep(2)  # delay
    GPIO.output(Main_Pwr, False)  # turn off main power by activating relay K8
    time.sleep(3)  # delay
    PS1_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS)  # read information to ads object from pin 2 of ADS1015
    print(PS1_V.value, PS1_V.voltage)  # print values read
    time.sleep(2)  # delay
"""




#I2C_setup()
Test_1()

# cleanup the GPIO pins before ending
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Might be a feature of your python package.  There might be some setter conversion going on or storage of pyobject pointers.  Try converting things to python floats before storing.  You can also print type or .__class__ of stuff to understand what you are storing.

Comment: Post all of your code, especially including the method "AnalogIn."  I expect you are assigning methods to the variables instead of values.

Comment: @JRE ok I will post the rest of the code but the AnalogIn function is from adafruit: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the code isn't doing what you think it is.

Look at this line:

```python
PS1_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS)
```

You seem to be under the impression that this line assigns the current "voltage" and "value" values to PS1_V.  It doesn't.

It assigns the object "AnalogIn" to PS1_V.  Every time you call PS1_V.value, the "AnalogIn" object reads a new value from the ADC. Every time you call PS1_V.voltage, the "AnalogIn" object reads a new value from the ADC.

This line of your output tells you that this is so:
[image]

PS1_V is an object of type "adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in.AnalogIn"

Here's the relevant section of AnalogIn:

```python
 @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        """Returns the value of an ADC pin as an integer."""
        return self._ads.read(
            self._pin_setting, is_differential=self.is_differential
        ) << (16 - self._ads.bits)

    @property
    def voltage(self) -> float:
        """Returns the voltage from the ADC pin as a floating point value."""
        volts = self.value * _ADS1X15_PGA_RANGE[self._ads.gain] / 32767
        return volts
```

As you can see, getting the "value" from the AnalogIn involves reading from the ADC.  Getting the "voltage" calls "value," so it again reads from the ADC.

The way it is written, you can never get a "value" and a "voltage" that match - you will always get a new value which implies a new voltage.

- The analog to digital converter itself isn't perfect - the value will vary a tiny bit with each call even if the input is perfectly steady.
- The signal you are measuring won't be perfectly steady - it will vary a tiny bit every time you measure it.

Make your life easy.  Simply assign the values and use only the stored values:

```python
PS1.value = PS1_V.value
PS1.voltage = PS1_V.voltage
print("PS1 : " , PS1) 
print("PS1 : " , PS1.value) 
print("PS1 : " , PS1.voltage)
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment. I was starting to get to the same conclusion after reading about the continuous mode and on-shot mode of the analog to digital convertor. So I was thinking I should use it in one-shot mode and when the value comes into be stored in my own object variable I just operate with that PS1 data because that's not the AnalogIn object and won't change after the data copy.

Comment: Even in oneshot mode, it will go out and get a new value every time you call AnalogIn.value.

Comment: ok, yeah i see. So just need to work with my own object called "Reading.value" where I copied the AnalogIn.value data to to have the easiest results.